# My submit button is not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My submit button is not working in ASP.NET MVC. It's already connected with database,but its not submit the new data in the database.

```
@model Student
<form method=" post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-secondary">New Applicant</h2>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="FName">First Name</label>
            <input asp-for="FName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="LName">Last Name</label>
            <input asp-for="LName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DOB">Date of Birth</label>
            <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="City">City</label>
            <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
        </div>
       

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Create</button>
        <a asp-controller="Student" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Back to list
        </a>
       
    </div>"
</form>
```

Comment: `<form method=" post">` - you need to be **careful** not to have **extra erroneous** spaces - like here before the "post" command! Be sure to use `<form method="post">` - no extra spaces!

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Besides marc_s mentioned on top for the extra space in the method. Did you try to place a breakpoint on your POST action in the controller whether the method is called and hit? And do check whether your request is sent to the correct API action by viewing the browser's DevTools --> Network tab.